# Printer error when I try to access print queue: "Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file..."

Tags: windows, windows-10, printer

Full error message:

> Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.

Why would my printer be giving me this error all of a sudden? I can't print anything either - the queue is stuck or something!

Comment: Which printer? Are you using the latest driver?

Answer (score 0):

Clear the Print Queue and restart

Click Start.
Type Command .
Right-click “Command Prompt” and select “Run as administrator“.

Type net stop spooler then press “Enter“.
Type del %systemroot%\System32\spool\printers* /Q then press “Enter“.
Type net start spooler then press “Enter“.
The print queue on your Windows should now be cleared.

If clearing the spooler fails to start the printer, clear it again , restart and reinstall your printer driver

Comment: I'm a bit hesitant to delete files from my system32 folder, do you have a link to an article which advises this?

Comment: Clearing print spooler files will not cause any issue. I have done this many times . Never any damage

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions of the spool folder, C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS. Make sure that CREATOR OWNER has at least READ and WRITE permissions on files and sub-folders. If you print via a server, this must be done on the server. If CREATOR OWNER is missing, add it and make sure it has the correct permissions.

This problem can happen if the spool folder is moved, e.g. to another drive.

Comment: I tried setting this, but it instantly gets reverted when I press "apply"

Comment: Sounds as if you don't have permission to make the change. Try logging in as administrator, and then setting it for the owner.

Comment: I'm logged in as domain admin and it warns me that I'm changing system directory permissions. In the advanced permission view they are right, but in the basic property window the are wrong

Answer (score -1):

Are you proceed to print a document and getting the "**Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file...**" message while launching the file? Then, the solutions you need to apply to fix the problem are as follows:

- Check and Edit the File permission.
- Locate the file Path, and then open it.
- Ensure that the file is present at your PC, and no antivirus tool is blocking to open it.

Comment: No, I get this error when I try to access the print queue by clicking on the queue button in the settings app. If I try to print something, it doesn't print and I get a message saying something like "checking printer status".

Comment: Please check the solution I posted above.  Also turn your printer off completely, wait 30 seconds and turn it on again.

Comment: Then, you can check the cable connections of the printer. After ensuring that the cable connections are OK, that is, after turning off the power of the printer, restart the printer as well as the computer. Hopefully, you will get the issue resolved.